# Controlling two objects' movement in ping pong game in Processing

Tags: processing

I'm trying to build a ping pong game with Processing language. For this two-player game I have two controllers at each end of the 'table'. I coded the movements of the players (up and down) by binding them to the keys: 
- w and s for player 1
- o and l for player 2
Although this works when I press them one at a time, I cannot figure out how to make them move simultaneously, as in pressing both w and o at the same time.
Here is my code:

```java
int x=535;
int y=350;
int dx=5;
int dy=5;
int pX=10;
int pY=520; 
int pX1=1870;
int pY1=520;
int pS=5;

void setup() {
  size(1920,1080);
} 

void draw() {
  background(0);
  rect(960,0,5,1080);
  rect(pX,pY,40,150);
  rect(pX1,pY1,40,150);
  ellipse(x,y,50,50);
  x=x+dx;
  y=y+dy;
  bounce();
  move();
  move1();
}

void bounce(){
   if(x>=1920 || x<=0){
     dx=-dx;
   }
   if(y>1080 || y<0){
     dy=-dy;
   }
}

void move(){
  if(keyPressed){
    if(key == 's'){
      pY+=pS;
    }else if (key == 'w'){
      pY-=pS;
    }
  }
}
void move1() {
  if(keyPressed){
    if(key == 'l'){
      pY1+=pS;
    }else if (key == 'o'){
      pY1-=pS;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please note that i still haven't coded collision into the game so don't mind that.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is create a `boolean` value for each key you care about. Then in the `keyPressed()` function, you set the corresponding variable to `true`, and in the `keyReleased()` function, you set the corresponding variable to `false`. Then in your `draw()` function, you check the variables to determine which keys are pressed.

Shameless self-promotion: I wrote a tutorial on getting user input available [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/input). Check out the **Handling Multiple Keys** section.